# Add function call inside ternary operator in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator, jsx

i want to call a function inside a ternary operator condition.
My code is like this:

```
{snapshot.Bid[0].Price !== 'undefined'
                  ? `(${initialOrderInfo.snapshot.Bid[0].Price}`
                    {renderCurrencySymbol(
                      initialOrderInfo.instrumentInfo.currency
                    )}
```

But it shows me multiple errors. Any ideas what should i do?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

**#1 Error**

You are missing `:`.

```
// example
? `(${initialOrderInfo.snapshot.Bid[0].Price}`
                        : {renderCurrencySymbol(
```

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

---

**#2 Error**

About your template string you used as first expression

```
(${initialOrderInfo.snapshot.Bid[0].Price}
```

Incorrect is  having `(` opening parenthesis, you are not closing it. Using parenthesis here is pointless.

You don't even need to use template string.

Valid code is

```
initialOrderInfo.snapshot.Bid[0].Price 
//or 
`${initialOrderInfo.snapshot.Bid[0].Price}`
```

---

But correct `JSX` in your case, assuming that `renderCurrencySymbol()` is a `class method` would be as follows:

```
{snapshot.Bid[0].Price !== 'undefined'
                  ? initialOrderInfo.snapshot.Bid[0].Price
                    : this.renderCurrencySymbol(
                      initialOrderInfo.instrumentInfo.currency
                    )}
```